# Can the metadata storage and the changelog execution be separated on Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase, impala

My issue is that I would like to manage an Impala database, but unfortunately Impala did not allow Liquibase to freely handle its two metadata manager tables (DATABASECHANGELOG, DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK). Thus I would like to know if it is possible to store these metadata management tables on let's say an Oracle SQL database but execute the statements in the changelogs with Impala. This would of course require maintaining two different connections, but I have no problem with that.

I am using the Liquibase Maven Plugin for this, and for the Impala connection I used this extension: https://github.com/eselyavka/liquibase-impala